# What is the two-way model-format compatibility?

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am reading [Deep Learning with JavaScript](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-javascript) but get bogged down by this line:

> Adding to the multidimensional capability of TensorFlow.js is its status as a first-class integrated part of the larger TensorFlow/Keras ecosystem, specifically its API consistency and two-way model-format compatibility with the Python libraries.

I wonder what it means by 'two-way model-format compatibility with the Python libraries.'? Does it mean that models(pb files) trained by normal Python Tensorflow can be loaded by TF.js networks or served by JavaScript?

If so, why do we need TensorFlow.js to support training? We can just train models using Python Tensorflow libraries and use JavaScript libraries for inference.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that models(pb files) trained by normal Python Tensorflow can be loaded by TF.js networks or served by JavaScript?

For standard models, yes, thats exactly what it means
But if you use custom ops or ops provided by some non-standard TF addon, then you'd have to re-implement them in TFJS yourself

> If so, why do we need TensorFlow.js to support training? We can just train models using Python Tensorflow libraries and use JavaScript libraries for inference

Not everyone is comfortable with **Python**, maybe someone wants to start with machine learning in **JS**

Also, what if I want to run training in browser using `WebGL` or `WebGPU`?
Not everyone has `CUDA`-enabled box to run GPU-accelerated training